# TimeField format in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, time-format, timefield

I'm writing an application in `Django` and using several `TimeFields` in a model. I only want to work with the time format hh:mm (not hh:mm:ss or hh p.m./a.m. or other things).
I have set the django setting `TIME_FORMAT = 'H:i'` and `USE_L10N = False` according to the documentation,

> `USE_L10N` overrides `TIME_FORMAT` if set to `True`

In my template I'm using input boxes automatically created by Django like:

```
{{formName.timeField}}
```

The problem is that as long as I introduce something like "10:00" and do a `POST`, when the `POST` is done Django (or whatever) turns it into "10:00:00" (so it adds the seconds).

- Is there a way to specify the format in which datetime fields display saved dates? If I could just use something like `|date:"H:i"` in the value of the input box that would do the trick.

On the other side I know I could do the input box manually (not directly using `{{formName.timeField}}`), but I've had some problems in the past with that so I would like to avoid that (at least for the moment).

There is also this similar question in [Django TimeField Model without seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240278/django-timefield-model-without-seconds), but the solution does not work (it gives me '`NoneType`' object has no attribute '`strptime`')

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had exactly this problem in my app, and solved it by passing a `format` parameter to Django's `TimeInput` widget:

```
from django import forms

class SettingsForm(forms.Form):
    delivery_time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
```

Comment: Just a note for future readers that the `TimeInput` widget's `format` parameter only controls the initial value output format of the field, not the input validation of the field. For input validation format, use `TimeField`'s `input_formats` parameter.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you have a format you want all `TimeFields` to use, you can add the `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` to your settings file. For example, `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p',)` will format your times as "5:30 PM".

The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS