# Django DateTimeField no seconds

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm struggling with one case - I would like to have a field in my data time field model but without seconds etc. just `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`.

I've been trying to do like this, but it doesn't work:

```
schedule_time = models.DateTimeField(format(['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M']), auto_now_add=True)
```

Could someone provide me a solution on any example?

I've also been looking for solutions there, but I haven't found anything that would help me.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue with help of my answer?

Comment: Here is another great answer, that works without modifying the setings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203449/4379151

Answer (score 2):

Set `DATETIME_FORMAT` in your `settings.py` as specified in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#datetime-format).

Since you don't want seconds to be displayed, you can choose the below format and update in settings.py :

`DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`

When `USE_L10N is True`, the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead. so you have to also do:

`USE_L10N = False`

Your `settings.py` will look like this after making changes:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
USE_L10N = False
```

You can also manually change the format when saving it with help
of `datetime` module.